# Maven multiple source directory module not working

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi module project in which some of the modules have multiple source directories (one for hand created code and one for generated code).

The project looks like:

```
Product
+-- pom.xml
+-- MagniCompCommon
   +-- src/main/java
   +-- src-gen
   +-- pom.xml
```

I am using the build-helper-maven-plugin to add the src-gen directory.  However, when I compile via "mvn clean install" in the Parent maven does not compile anything in src-gen nor include it in the classpath when it tries to compile src/main/java files.  Since many of the java code in `src/main/java` reference the src-gen code, the compile fails.

Here is Parent pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.magnicomp</groupId>
  <artifactId>Product</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>


  <modules>
    <module>MagniCompCommon</module>
    <module>Model</module>
    <module>Common</module>
    <!-- <module>Agent</module> -->
    <!-- <module>Doc</module> -->
  </modules>

    <properties>
        <!-- MagniComp common -->
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version> <!-- was 4.3.10.Final -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- Product specific -->
        <!-- <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> -->
        <jersey.glassfish.version>2.21</jersey.glassfish.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>3.0</javax.servlet.version>
        <bouncy.version>1.51</bouncy.version>       
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                      <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <sources>
                            <source>src-gen</source>
                          </sources>
                        </configuration>
                      </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <!-- Use Java 8 (default is 5) -->
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

I have also tried using `${project.basedir}/src-gen` for `<source>` but that made no difference.

Here is MagniCompCommon pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.magnicomp</groupId>
        <artifactId>Product</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>MagniCompCommon</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
.... snip ...
```

Comment: By which tools are those things in `src-gen` generated ? (XSD/REST/WSDL?)

Answer (score 1):

move  to child :

```
   <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                      <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <sources>
                            <source>src-gen</source>
                          </sources>
                        </configuration>
                      </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
</plugins>
```

- why use pluginManagement => is only a way to share the same plugin.
- maven-compiler-plugin u can put it in pluginManagement put not others plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Created multi module maven project (same as yours) and added the below build tags to the child module MagniCompCommon pom.xml file. Worked fine for me with no compilation errors

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>src/main/java/**/*.java</include>
            <include>src-gen/**/*.java</include>
        </includes>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent POM has

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

This means that this POM does not have a normal build lifecycle, there's no code there.

Move the `build-helper-maven-plugin` description from the parent project to the POM of `MagniCompCommon`, within `build.plugins` and *not* `build.pluginmanagement.plugins`.

Edit: also, if you do not check in your `src-gen` into source control (and since it's generated it's better not to), use `target/generated-sources` instead and then no `build-helper-maven-plugin` will be necessary.

Comment: I actually tried that and it had no effect.  I moved the entire <build>...</build> content from Parent pom.xml to MagniCompCommon pom.xml.  I also previously tried leaving the maven-compiler-plugin section in Parent pom.xml and moving just the build-helper-maven-plugin to MagniCompCommon pom.xml.  That had no effect either.

Comment: You did *not* read my comment fully. Your problem stems from the fact that you've set your plugin description within `pluginManagement`, which indicates default values for a plugin, *if that plugin is referenced in the build*, *in a subproject*. Move it to your subproject, in the `plugins` tag.

Comment: Ahhh!  Yes you are right.  I missed that.  It works great now.  Thank you VERY much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version of MagniCompCommon pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src-gen</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```